# Converting different strings to NSDate - 1 is correct, the 2nd is a duplicate of the 1st

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, ios8.1

For some reason, this code is not converting the second string correctly; this is the code:

```
    NSLog(@"\n\nsearchStartTime: %@  searchEndTime: %@",searchStartTime, searchEndTime);
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a"];
    startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:searchStartTime];
    endDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:searchEndTime];

    NSLog(@"\n\nstartDate: %@    endDate: %@", startDate, endDate);
```

This the definition and value of the **searchStartTime** and **searchEndTime**:

> searchStartTime: 2015-03-05 08:30 AM  searchEndTime: 2015-03-05 09:30 AM

This is the result from NSLog:

> startDate: 2015-03-05 08:30:00 +0000    endDate: 2015-03-05 08:30:00 +0000

What's wrong with my code here?  I want to take these two date/time objects and use them in a NSPredicate to compare dates in a Core Data record.

Comment: K is for hour in am/pm (0~11), h is for hour in am/pm (1~12). So choose K or h depending on how the tile just past noon or midnight is displayed: 00:01 am or 12:01 am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all comes down to knowing your format code strings. You are misusing `"HH"` here so the hour is coming out wrong.

Another problem is that you are not capturing the error. By calling `dateFromString:`, you are missing out on your chance to hear about errors. Use `getObjectValue:forString:range:error:` to learn of problems.

Anyway, I substituted `"hh"` where you have `"HH"` and the answers came out right:

```
NSString* searchStartTime = @"2015-03-05 08:30 AM";
NSString* searchEndTime = @"2015-03-05 09:30 AM";
NSLog(@"\n\nsearchStartTime: %@  searchEndTime: %@",searchStartTime, searchEndTime);
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"];
NSDate* startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:searchStartTime];
NSDate* endDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:searchEndTime];
NSLog(@"\n\nstartDate: %@    endDate: %@", startDate, endDate);
```

> ```
> startDate: 2015-03-05 16:30:00 +0000    endDate: 2015-03-05 17:30:00 +0000
> ```

I am in California, and the time is shown relative to London, so if you subtract the time difference you'll see that this is correct.

Comment: Thanks matt... this is a case of not being able to see the "trees" in the "forest"... I knew this, just couldn't see it.  Thanks again.. SD

Answer (score 1):

One error is "HH" which is 24-hour tine but you are also using "a" for an & pm.

Instead use "hh" for 12-hour time.

Example:

```
NSString *searchStartTime = @"2015-03-05 08:30 AM";
NSString *searchEndTime = @"2015-03-05 09:30 AM";

NSLog(@"\n\nsearchStartTime: %@  searchEndTime: %@", searchStartTime, searchEndTime);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"];
NSDate *startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:searchStartTime];
NSDate *endDate   = [dateFormatter dateFromString:searchEndTime];

NSLog(@"\n\nstartDate: %@ endDate: %@", startDate, endDate);
```

Output:

> searchStartTime: 2015-03-05 08:30 AM  searchEndTime: 2015-03-05 09:30 AM
>   startDate: 2015-03-05 13:30:00 +0000 endDate: 2015-03-05 14:30:00 +0000

See: [ICU Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)
Also: [Date Field SymbolTable.](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table)

Comment: Thank you... I gave the points to matt because he answered it first; I appreciate your time tho'... SD

Comment: Notice that both Matt and I put together a complete test case, that is a good thing to do when you have a problem.